# LOG4CXX to Android Log

Tags: android, logging, android-ndk, log4cxx

How can I easily replace the log4cxx for android log?

I'm trying to re-define as:

```
#define LOG4CXX_INFO(logger, message) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, message)
```

But a compilation error is showed:

```
xxxxx.cpp:122:13: error: no match for 'operator<<' in '"Could not open file " << fileName'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is best to write a custom [Appender](http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4cxx/Appender) wrapping __android_log_print.

See [Log4cxx custom appender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874661/log4cxx-custom-appender).